# Mysql nested query to get child entities from single table

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a mysql table called as `tbl_company` and it looks like this

```
|------------|--------------|-------------------|
| Company_id | Company_name | Company_Parent_id |
|------------|--------------|-------------------|
|            |              |                   |
|            |              |                   |
|------------|--------------|-------------------|
```

Here the company_parent_id is nothing but the company_id of the parent company_name of a particular company.

What i want to do is write a single nested query which gives me data like below

```
|------|-----------|-----------|-----------|-----------|
| Root | 1st Level | 2nd Level | 3rd Level | 4th Level |
|------|-----------|-----------|-----------|-----------|
|      |           |           |           |           |
|      |           |           |           |           |
|------|-----------|-----------|-----------|-----------|
```

where i will be providing the root company_id and will order based on that so that the result should turn out to be like

```
|------|-----------|-----------|-----------|-----------|
| Root | 1st Level | 2nd Level | 3rd Level | 4th Level |
|------|-----------|-----------|-----------|-----------|
|  abc |    def    |           |           |           |
|  abc |    def    |    efg    |           |           |
|  abc |    def    |    efg    |    hij    |           |
|  abc |    def    |    efg    |    hij    |  lmn      |
|------|-----------|-----------|-----------|-----------|
```

How should i approach this? Any help would be great!

**EDIT:**

I tried a query myself,its not returning all the results

```
SELECT l1.Company_name AS lev1, l2.Company_name as lev2, l3.Company_name as lev3, l4.Company_name as lev4
FROM tbl_company AS l1
LEFT JOIN tbl_company AS l2 ON l2.Company_Parent_id = l1.Company_id
LEFT JOIN tbl_company AS l3 ON l3.Company_Parent_id = l2.Company_id
LEFT JOIN tbl_company AS l4 ON l4.Company_Parent_id = l3.Company_id
WHERE l1.Company_Parent_id = 0 and l1.Company_id != 0 
ORDER BY l1.Company_name ASC;
```

Can someone help me make this sql work, please?

Comment: i would prefer to keep it as a select query itself

Comment: Check this out: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/7147/find-highest-level-of-a-hierarchical-field-with-vs-without-ctes/7161#7161

Comment: Thanks for the link i'll try that, but im really looking for nested select query

Comment: Why aren't you sure whether your query works or not?

Comment: I mean it is working, just not returning the right set for result

Comment: I don't think you can do it with a single straight SQL statement, as previously stated, stored proc is probably the way to go